# Stop a PowerShell script GUI while in a loop

Tags: loops, powershell-2.0

I have a PowerShell script for which I've done a GUI. 
Every time a do or for loop is running the GUI becomes unresponsive and have to wait until it's done before I can close the GUI or press any other button.
The problem is anoying when for any number of reasons the loop runs infinitely and the only way to stop it is to kill PowerShell from task manager.
I've tried using `break` but this causes some sort java error although it stop and kills they gui...but I don't want to have the error.
If I use `break` in the script without GUI the script stops.
Is there a way to have the GUI responding when a loop is running and to stop the script when ever I what it to stop?

Answer (score 0):

You could run the PowerShell script as a job and have the GUI polling the status of that job (in a loop with so you can still react on user input).

Cancelling a script is then also possible by just cancelling the job.